# C++ spliting string by delimiters and keeping the delimiters in result

Tags: c++, regex, delimiter, split

I'm looking for a way to split string by multiple delimiters using regex in C++ but without losing the delimiters in output, keeping the delimiters with splitted parts in order, for example:

Input

> aaa,bbb.ccc,ddd-eee;

Output

> aaa , bbb . ccc , ddd - eee ;

I've found some solutions for this but all in C# or java, looking for some C++ solution, preferably without using Boost.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could build your solution on top of the example for [`regex_iterator`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_iterator/regex_iterator/). If, for example, you know your delimiters are comma, period, semicolon, and hyphen, you could use a regex that captures either a delimiter or a series of non-delimiters:

```
([.,;-]|[^.,;-]+)
```

Drop that into the sample code and you end up with [something like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02c34c2928876e64):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main ()
{
  // the following two lines are edited; the remainder are directly from the reference.
  std::string s ("aaa,bbb.ccc,ddd-eee;");
  std::regex e ("([.,;-]|[^.,;-]+)");   // matches delimiters or consecutive non-delimiters

  std::regex_iterator<std::string::iterator> rit ( s.begin(), s.end(), e );
  std::regex_iterator<std::string::iterator> rend;

  while (rit!=rend) {
    std::cout << rit->str() << std::endl;
    ++rit;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Try substituting in any other regular expressions you like.

Answer (score 2):

For your case, splitting your input string according to the word boundary `\b` except the one at the first will give you the desired output.

```
(?!^)\b
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rJ9aU8/1)

OR

```
(?<=\W)(?!$)|(?!^)(?=\W)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rJ9aU8/3)

- `(?<=\W)(?!$)` Matches the boundaries which exists next to a non-word character but not the boundary present at the last.
- `|` OR
- `(?!^)(?=\W)` Matches the boundary which is followed by a non-word character except the one at the start.

Escape the backslash one more time if necessary.

Comment: For some reason these won't work for me, unhandled exception error. Tried adding extra backslashes, doesn't help. I'm using VS2013.