# Qt- Splitting strings but keep the delimiters in array

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to split `string` using `delimiters` but I want to keep the `delimiters` in the array. Code :

```
QRegExp rx("(\\+|\\-|\\*|\\/)");
QStringList query = text.split(rx);
```

Input:

> 2+3

This will give me an array
2,3 but I want 2,+,3

Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ spliting string by delimiters and keeping the delimiters in result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27706443/c-spliting-string-by-delimiters-and-keeping-the-delimiters-in-result)

Comment: Nope its in C++ and I need in C++ Qt

Comment: @F.Bartos The regular expression is the same

Comment: I also recommend using [QRegularExpression](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html) instead of QRegExp

Comment: @F.Bartos: You can access the standard library from a Qt application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a function in Qt that does it for you, but you could easily reconstruct it. Pseudo code, because I don't know the exact syntax:

```
QStringList query = text.split(rx);
QStringList queryWithSeparators;

size_t pos = 0;
for (const auto part : query) {
    queryWithSeparators.append(part);
    pos += part.length;

    if (pos + 1 < text.length) {
        // we know that the separators are all 1 character long
        queryWithSeparators.append(text.substring(pos, 1));
        pos += 1;
    }
}
```

This is ugly and difficult to understand. From you example it seems that you are trying to parse a mathematical expression. It's much easier to create a tokenizer which reads character-by-character than trying to use regular expressions for this task.

(If you really want to use `split`, you could first split it for all `+`, then split these strings at all `-` etc. This way you would know exactly what the separators are.)

Answer (score 1):

You can have a work around solution for your problem.
Try this code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QRegExp>

int main()
{
    QString text = "2+3-3-4/5+9+0"; // Input, you can write you own code to take input
    QRegExp rx("(\\+|\\-|\\*|\\/)");
    QStringList query = text.split(rx);

    int count = 0;
    int pos = 0;
    while ((pos = rx.indexIn(text, pos)) != -1) {
        ++count;
        pos += rx.matchedLength();
        query.insert(count * 2-1, QString(text[pos - 1]));
    }
    return 0;
}
```